# Clear All button onPressed triggered but does not clear the list items and rebuild the listview

Tags: flutter

I have a widget button Clear All with `onPressed()`:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    MyCart().clearEverything();
    _buildListItem();
  });
},
```

The clear all will trigger code below

```
clearEverything() {
    cartList.clear();
    print(cartList);
    notifyListeners();
    print('hell..');
}
```

Even though onPressed is triggered, it does not clear the list items and rebuild the listview. What is wrong?

Comment: Hey there, try to edit your question and use the tools for marking code as a code sample to make it more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make the cartList `static` and use it like `MyCart.cartList`. Right now it will always make a new instance of it every time you call `MyCart()`, so the new list will be cleared but when you again call `MyCart().cartList` the new list is not cleared.

```
class MyCart {
  static List<String> cartList = [...];
  clearEverything() {
    cartList.clear();
    print(cartList);
    notifyListeners();
    print('hell..');
  }
}
```